# Prove that $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right) = \pi - x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\tan(x)}\right) = \pi - x$$

I solved a mechanic problem and found the left side of the equation mentionned in the title, to find out the validity of the result, I checked the solution and I found the right side of the equation, It is obvious that the statement is true but I can't prove it .

Can you? :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true for $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: $ \tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{\tan x}\bigg) =\frac \pi 2 -x $

Comment: I've made a mistake, it's pi/2  not pi  :( sorry !

Answer (score 2):

Convince yourself that $\cot x = \tan\left(\frac\pi 2 - x\right)$ for some appropriate domain for $x$. For instance, draw a right angled triangle.

Then, as $\arctan$ is monotonic,

$$\arctan(\cot x) = \frac\pi 2 - x$$

Comment: I think you want to restrict x to $0<x<\pi$.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not true... $\;\;\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{\tan x}\big) \neq \pi-x$
 in general. Take, for example, $x=10$. We have
$$\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{\tan 10}\bigg) \approx 1.396$$
However, we also have that
$$\pi - 10 \approx -6.858...$$
It is true though that $\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{\tan x}\big) = \tan^{-1} (\cot x )$, by the defining identity of $\cot x$. From this, we can see from the following graph that this equals $\frac{\pi}{2} - x$ in the domain $(0,\pi)$.
[image]
For other domains you can see from the graph that a simple vertical translation of the function (by a factor of $\pi$) suffices. Thus, you can easily calculate $\tan^{-1}(\cot x)$ for any value of $x \neq n\pi$, where $n$ is any integer

Comment: thanx a lot actually I've made a mistake it's pi/2 :)